# Converting .txt file to .xls file using opentxt method using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need a help with converting a .txt to an .excel file.

For example, the below file consists 7 lines and I want to convert the .txt to excel from Line #4 to Line #5

Sample.txt

```
1...........
 2Sample Text
 3.....
 4xxx|abcd|12-12-2014|1234.56
 5yyy|bcdefg|12-12-2014|3234.56
 6Total number
 7this is last line
```

I wrote the code, reading each line and using Split function, but this takes lot of time as my .txt files contains thousands of lines.

Comment: You should give more details about the format of your .txt file. It seems that your .txt file is "|" separated. I do not know about .xls format but I guess it is a binary format. I guess you need to convert to CSV that excel understands.

Answer (score 0):

Open it as a normal file (workbooks.open blah blah) then use this:

```
Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, OtherChar:="|", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1)
    Rows("1:3").Delete
```

First command splits across columns using the Pipe "|" as a delimiter then the second line deletes rows 1:3 as you said you don't want those rows.